# LibGDX texture won't draw on Android 4.3

Tags: android, textures, screen, libgdx

I have a main class extending Game, a splash screen implementing Screen, batch, camera and texure in the splash screen class.
On some my devices it runs correctly (Xperia SP 4.1.2, Xperia Neo V 2.3.4, GalaxyTab 8.9 4.0.4), but on my Nexus 7 with Android... 4.3 (!) texture is not drawing.
But texture in project which implements ApplicationListener works correctly in all of them.
I'm using lastest nightly build of LibGDX. What is wrong?

Comment: Please show some code for loading the texture and rendering the texture.  Please read http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ke1GLj3L
http://pastebin.com/RBMhUjYD
Code.

And sorry for my english :/

Comment: Your English is great.  Your code looks fine, too.  (BTW, you should be able to edit the code into your existing question).  Maybe something is up with your texture?  What version of OpenGL are you targeting?  What is the format and size of your image?  (Is it the same texture in all the cases you outlined?)

Comment: Hah, problem is solved. OpenGL target was 2.0, but... on Nexus (tegra3 problem?) work only textures with power-of-two dimensions... That's a bit strange.

Comment: Yeah, that's very strange.  OpenGL2.0 should not have texture size requirements.  Did you set 'config.useGL20 = true;' in the AndroidApplicationConfiguration: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplicationConfiguration.html#useGL20

Comment: Also, please add your solution as an "answer" below so the question doesn't look "unanswered".

Comment: Yup, I did. And still doesn't work on Nexus. Anyway, I will use POT dimensions, it looks safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hah, problem is solved. OpenGL target was 2.0, but... on Nexus (tegra3 problem?) work only textures with power-of-two dimensions... That's a bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on nexus Samsung Google Galaxy Nexus I9250 or Samsung Google Nexus 3 or Samsung Galaxy X , and in this case the problem is that these devices can not render images that they dont have power of two dimension. So for example if a texture size is (54, 1000) it should be resized to (64,1024). this problem doesnt exist on Sumsung s4 mini however. the way I was rendering textures was loading the model from assetmanager.

```
  //AssetManager : is a class for loading models
    AssetManager assets = new AssetManager();
    public ModelInstance modelInstancePlane;
    public Model modelPlane;
    String plane="plane.g3db";
    assets.load(plane, Model.class);
    //If you want to block and make sure all assets are loaded
    assets.finishLoading();
    modelPlane = assets.get(plane, Model.class);
    modelInstancePlane= new ModelInstance(modelPlane);
```